# How to add new table in existing module using UpgradeSchema in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, upgradeschema

```
class UpgradeSchema implements  UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface     $setup,ModuleContextInterface     $context){
$setup->startSetup();
            if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.0', '<=')) {
            $installer = $setup;
            $installer->startSetup();

         $table = $installer->getConnection()
        ->newTable($installer->getTable('my_booster'))
        ->addColumn(
            'review_id',
            Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Review ID'
        )
        ->addColumn('pros', Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, ['nullable' => false], 'What I like about this product')
        ->addColumn('cons', Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, ['nullable' => false], 'What I dislike about this product')
        ->addColumn('title', Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, ['nullable' => false], 'Custom Title')
        ->addColumn('review_comments', Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, ['nullable' => false], 'Custom  Comments')
        ->addColumn('send_to', Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, ['nullable' => false], 'Send reply to Customer')
        ->addColumn('helpful', Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, ['nullable' => false], 'Was this review helpful?')
        ->addColumn('product_quality', Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, ['nullable' => false], 'Product Quality ')
        ->addColumn('Product Value', Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, ['nullable' => false], 'Product Value')
        ->addColumn('product_price', Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, ['nullable' => false], 'Product Price')
        ->addColumn('image', Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, ['nullable' => false], 'Viemo');

        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

}

I am using this script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have got the correct working answer.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;


class UpgradeSchema implements  UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
  public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.2', '<')) {
      $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $setup->getTable("enter table name here"),
        'enter new column name here',
        [
          "type" => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
          "nullable" => true,
          "comment" => "xample"
        ]
      );
      $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $setup->getTable("enter table name here"),
        'enter new second column name here',
        [
          "type" => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
          "nullable" => true,
          "comment" => "Xample 2"
        ]
      );
      $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $setup->getTable("enter table name here"),
        'enter new third column name here',
        [
          "type" => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
          "nullable" => true,
          "comment" => "Xample 3"
        ]
      );

    }
    $setup->endSetup();
}
}
```

also you need to change etc/module.xml file. where `setup_version="2.0.1" schema_version="2.0.1"` .

Comment: should change to whaetever we are using here? $context->getVersion(), '2.0.2'

Comment: how to create primary key with integer?

Comment: @jafarpinjar ->addColumn(
              'voting_id', 
              Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, 
              11,
              ['nullable' => true, 'primary' => true, 'auto_increment' => true],
              'Voting ID'
              )

Comment: I am getting base table not found error

Comment: if you please post your code then i can understand what actually problem is.

Comment: hi @Ali, here is my full question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/259126/cretate-new-table-to-existing-module-in-magento2/

Comment: did you search the table "product_temp_cart" in your database? as you said you forget to run installSchema.php when you created your module then how you can upgrade your table if its not created?

Comment: I need to create table from upgradeschema instead of installschema

Comment: upgradeScheme only works when you have already created your table.

Comment: My question is, I created module, forgot to include setup folder fully, module created now, next I need table to create, so I need to create new module?? Not able to create table with existing module??

Comment: i have answered your question. please look at that.

Comment: if did not worked let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{

    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $setup->startSetup();

        $version = $context->getVersion();
        $connection = $setup->getConnection();

        if (version_compare($version, '2.0.0') < 0) {
            $connection->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('my_booster'),
                'author_id',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'comment' => 'Author ID',

                ]
            );

        }
    }
```

Comment: kindly mention the issue as well.

Comment: here is the issue  if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.0', '<=')) , withi which you are comparing

Comment: try this if (version_compare($version, '2.0.0') < 0)

Comment: your answer is not working for me.

Comment: How to copy existing table structure to the new table while install module? @sherazkhan